# localizations of $k[x, y, z]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, noetherian

In an exercise sheet I once claimed that for noetherian domains $R$ and $f \in R$ one has 
$$
R_f = \bigcap_{\phantom{n}\mathfrak{p} \not \ni f\\ \operatorname{ht} \mathfrak{p} =1} R_\mathfrak{p} \tag{1}
$$
with $\mathfrak{p}$ always denoting a prime ideal in $R$. I also claimed that for any prime $\mathfrak{q} \subset R$ 
$$
R_\mathfrak{q} = \bigcap_{\phantom{n}\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{q}\\ \operatorname{ht} \mathfrak{p} =1} R_\mathfrak{p} \tag{2}
$$

The instructor commented

> this is not true in general, see for example $R = k[x, y, z]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$.

I am not sure whether this referred to $(1), (2)$ or both (although I am still convinced that $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$).

While I see that the arguments I gave for $(2)$ are flawed I haven't been able to figure out how the counterexample works. Any pointers for that?

Comment: Though I am not sure of the example of your instructor, both (1) and (2) are false in general. The example I have in mind is $R=k[[x^4, x^3y, xy^3,y^4]]$. In (2), this  ring is already local, but smaller than the intersection of localizations at height one primes. In (1), take $f=1$, and it reduces to (2).

Comment: @Mohan Could you elaborate? What are the height 1 primes in your ring?

Comment: What they are not so important. This is a two dimensional ring with an isolated singularity, so the intersection of all localizations at height one primes gives the integral closure of $R$ and $R$ is not integrally closed.